# Singleton metaclass for each argument set compatible with Pickle

Tags: python, singleton

I am creating a metaclass which ensures that instances of an actual class `A` are kind of singletons. But rather than having only single instance of `A`, I would like to have one instance per argument set given to `A`.

That is

```
class A(metaclass=ArgumentSingleton):
    pass

r = A()
s = A()
t = A(1)
u = A(1)
v = A('hi')

print(r is s)  # True
print(r is t)  # False
print(t is u)  # True
print(v is u)  # False
print(v is r)  # False
```

Moreover, the property of 'being a singleton' must survive pickling.

That is

```
a = A()

with open('tmp.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pkl.dump(a, f)

with open('tmp.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    b = pkl.load(f)

print(a is b)  # True
```

For example Sympy is capable of doing that with their constants (such as `pi`) and I tried similar approach.

```
class ArgumentSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            self._args = args
            print('Here in __init__')

        def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol):
            return type(self), (*self._args,)

        init = '__init__'
        reduce = '__reduce_ex__'
        method_absence = [
            init not in class_dict,
            reduce not in class_dict
        ]

        if all(method_absence):
            class_dict[init] = __init__
            class_dict[reduce] = __reduce_ex__
        elif any(method_absence):
            raise ArgumentSingletonException(
                f"Either both methods '{init}', '{reduce}' are defined or "
                f"none of them in class: {name}"
            )

        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict)

        return new_class

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        key = (cls, *args, *kwargs.items())
        if key not in ArgumentSingleton._instances:
            ArgumentSingleton._instances[key] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[key]
```

The code depends quite deeply (at least to my standards) on inner workings of Python and I am afraid of any hidden bugs and hidden problems.

The purpose of controling presence of `__init__` and `__reduce_ex__` is to explicitly move responsibility for `__reduce_ex__` to the creators of the class `A` in case they decide to provide their `__init__`.

Any comments or suggestions appreciated!

So far, I am aware of the fact that the arguments must be hashable. That is not problem for me, as this construction is meant to speed up comparison of my complex hashable objects.

Comment: Hey, welcome to the community! The 2nd code snippet, where you show the pickling and unpickling, makes use of a variable `b` that is not defined! For the sake of clarity and correctness you might want to add it there :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for welcome and pointing out the error. Fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I have rolled back your edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of having to define either neither or both of `__init__` and `__reduce_ex__` is to set `_args`.
However you can just set `_args` in `__call__` and then use the one you've set in your `__reduce_ex__`.
<sub>**Note**: untested</sub>

```py
class ArgumentSingleton(type):
    __INSTANCES = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict):
        def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol):
            return partial(type(self), *self.__args, **self.__kwargs), ()

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        class_dict.setdefault('__init__', __init__)
        class_dict.setdefault('__reduce_ex__', __reduce_ex__)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, class_dict)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        key = (cls, args, frozendict(kwargs))
        if None is (self := cls.__INSTANCES.get(key)):
            self = cls.__INSTANCES[key] = super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            self.__args, self.__kwargs = key[1:]
        return self
```

Now we should be able to see we can just stop defining a metaclass by;

1. changing `__call__` to `__new__`, and
2. defining a default `__reduce_ex__` on the base class.

```py
from frozendict import frozendict
from functools import partial

class Singleton:
    __INSTANCES = {}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        key = (cls, args, frozendict(kwargs))
        if None is (self := cls.__INSTANCES.get(key)):
            self = cls.__INSTANCES[key] = super().__new__(cls)
            self.__args, self.__kwargs = key[1:]
        return self

    def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol: int):
        return partial(type(self), *self.__args, **self.__kwargs), ()

class A(Singleton):
    pass


# passes all your tests and the following one
a = A("hi")
b = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(a))
assert a is b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it gets little problematic when allowing keyword arguments. Please, see my edit.

Comment: @TomášHons My aim is to simplify your code not change how your code functions. Since your code didn't correctly handle kwargs my changes don't.

Comment: Well, I my solution explicitly forbid them, which I see as better than allow them and silently introduce weird behavior. I pointed that out for anyone who wants to use the solution (me and you included). My intention was not to complain but to raise awareness of the possible problem. Your solution has +1 from me, as it helped me a lot and probably will be accepted (I want let the question open for others for some time).

Comment: @TomášHons Yeah using `frozendict` would be better here as you know. Additionally you are unlikely to have weird gotchas. For example if a subclass change the `__init__` in your code to include `**kwargs` your code has the same issue, without changing to use `frozendict`.

Comment: Right, that is true, it's not bullet proof (maybe forbid `__init__` completely). Similarly, I still ponder whether use the `Singleton` should be a class or metaclass. With metaclass it is possible to avoid invoking `__init__` completely when re-using an instance which is probably desirable.

Comment: @TomášHons My 2c with the code you've provided I currently see no benefits to using a metaclass that a normal class doesn't allow. However, ensuring `__init__` is only ever called once could be a benefit of using a metaclass, with different/more code. You could just move `__new__` to the metaclass and have like a mix between my two examples above. Additionally I'm confident you can make the right decision, worst case you can ask for another review :)

Comment: Right, I agree :) I will just add the `frozendict` to your solution, in order to mark it as accepted with a clear conscience (in case someone will use it in future). Thank you for your work!

Comment: The edit intended to fix the error in the call `super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. However, too short edits are forbidden, so I added a note there to fulfill the 'requirements' on edit. Also, the note itself makes sense for anyone who wants to use the code.

Comment: @TomášHons The note is better served as a comment.

Comment: Yet, still the original intent to fix the code is valid. So please, remove the `cls` argument, as I do not have the ability.

Comment: @TomášHons You're not following the etiquette of Stack Exchange sites. Everyone thinks their edits and opinions are right. And whilst you may be right, the proper course of action is to comment. Two people rejected your edit for misusing the edit button. Please leave your note as a comment.

Comment: Now I am concerned about fixing the call on the line `self = cls.__INSTANCES[key] = super().__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. I wrote the note **only** because I was not allow post such short edit (though I believe in the message of the note in itself). Now I send another edit to mark my point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I will probably use.

It's a bit more complicated, but

- Enables the class `A` to define its own signature of `__init__` (without introducing new problems).
- The signature is correctly handled even when it uses default arguments.
- The `__init__` method is truly invoked only once (which appears to me as more logical behavior).

The first two properties are ensured via `inspect` module and manipulating with the actual signature of `A.__init__`.
The second property comes from the use of metaclass and modifying behavior of its `__call__` method.
Modifying `__new__` in the superclass of `A` is not enough for this purpose.

```py
from frozendict import frozendict
from functools import partial
import inspect

class ArgumentSingletonMeta(type):
    __instances = {}

    @staticmethod
    def __get_trimmed_signature(init_method):
        # Removes 'self' argument from the signature
        sig = inspect.signature(init_method)
        params = tuple(sig.parameters.values())
        return sig.replace(parameters=params[1:])

    @staticmethod
    def __get_normalized_arguments(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        sig = ArgumentSingletonMeta.__get_trimmed_signature(cls.__init__)
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        bound.apply_defaults()
        return bound

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        normalized = ArgumentSingletonMeta.\
            __get_normalized_arguments(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        key = (cls, normalized.args, frozendict(normalized.kwargs))
        if None is (self := cls.__instances.get(key)):
            self = cls.__instances[key] = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            self._args, self._kwargs = key[1:]
        return self

class ArgumentSingleton(metaclass=ArgumentSingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        # self._args = args
        # self._kwargs = kwargs

    def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol: int):
        return partial(type(self), *self._args, **self._kwargs), ()
```

Note that it is probably more clear to assign the `self._args` and `self._kwargs` attributes in `ArgumentSingleton`'s `__init__`.
However, setting them in `ArgumentSingletonMeta`'s `__call__` is more efficient, as the `args` and `kwargs` are shared between the `__instances` dict and the actual instances.

Now try the following code:

```py
import pickle as pkl

class A(ArgumentSingleton):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=1):
        super().__init__(x, y, z)

a = A(x=0, y=1)
b = A(0, 1)
c = A(0, 1, z=1)

print(a is b)
print(a is c)

with open('tmp.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pkl.dump(a, f)

with open('tmp.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    b = pkl.load(f)

print(a is b)
```

Please comment if you see any hidden problem (even from software engineering point of view).
So far, I can't see any, but I would like to know if there are any :)